# Can't make SQL queries from javascript, throwing error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am querying from save_row function of java script by referring global variable of connection. Its throwing the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: con is not defined

Here con is global variable that holding the data base connection. And con is defined in js file and trying to access in script file.

This is my connection related code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.info("Email Sender app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: ""
});

//Here APIs
app.post('/transactionhistories', function (req, res) {
            con.query('SELECT * FROM booking_event WHERE booking_event.creationTime BETWEEN ? AND ? AND booking_event.status IN (?)', [startDate, endDate, status], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                var index = 0;
                var html = '<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} </style>' ;
                for (x in result) {
                    //Some custom code
                    html = html +
                        '<tr id="' + id + '"><td>'+
                        '<input type="button" id=' + edit_button + ' value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row(' + index + ')">' +
                        '<input type="button" id=' + save_button + ' value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row(' + index + ')">' +
                        '<input type="button" id=' + send_mail + ' value="Mail" class="mail" onclick="mail_row(' + index + ')">'
                        + '</td>' + '</tr>';
                    index++;
                }
                html = html + '<script>' +
                    function save_row(no) {
                        //Defined the queries here using the values.
                        //Here getting error.......................
                        con.query(queries, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            if (result)
                                alert("SUCCESS");
                            else
                                alert("FAILED");
                        });
                    }
                    + '</script>';
                html = html + '</table><br>' + '<a href="/">Back</a>';
                res.send(html);
            });
});
```

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   var html ='<form style="border: solid 1px #000000;padding: 5px" action="/transactionhistories" method="post">' +
        '<h2>Transactions Histories</h2>' +
        '<table><tr>' +
        '<td>Start Date :</td>' +
        '<td><input type="date" name="startdate" /></td>' +
        '<td>End Date :</td>' +
        '<td><input type="date" name="enddate" /></td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Based on Status :</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select name="status">' +
        '<option value="" selected>Select</option>' +
        '<option value="FAILED">FAILED</option>' +
        '<option value="BOOKED">BOOKED</option>' +
        '<option value="PAYMENT_PENDING">PAYMENT_PENDING</option>' +
        '<option value="REFUNDED">REFUNDED</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Password :</td>' +
        '<td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Access Code" /></td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr><td><button type="submit">Show Reports</button></td></tr></table>' +
        '</form><br><br>'
    ;
    res.send(html);
});
```

How to resolve this issues? Or is this right way to make query from scripts tag? I am new on JavaScript and Node.js

Comment: console.log(con) right after the createConnection statement. If mysql.createConnection() fails for some reason, con would be undefined...leading to your error

Comment: i suppose this is not the exact connection code : var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: ""
});  . If you have not blank data (of course...) try before the string connection outside via mysqlworkbench for example if it is correct

Comment: you don't create a connection so you can connect to the database

Comment: @ BUcorp I have not given the data base credential over here, it doesn't mean it's not connecting.

Comment: How many files are involved in this process? You mentioned that `con` is global - where does that happen, and how, and if it's happening in another file why is it defined again here? Try to provide examples that are as close to what you're working with as possible. If you have more than one file, enter a code snippet for each with the relevant code included. Understanding architecture can be very helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Can you please try initialising con inside the function(req, res)?

Comment: Yes tried, Still same issues

Comment: Details in your example suggest you might want to spend more time with the documentation for these frameworks as well as some tutorials. Trying to incorporating this much HTML and JS into your response object is an ill advised approach. Consider finding and using a view engine such as `EJS` or `Handlebars`. It's also unclear how your variables are getting defined. Your `POST` route is accepting form data but you never access it via `req.body`. Perhaps follow this tutorial, update and test your code accordingly. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_form_data.htm